# laravel livewire reading session message throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'fingerprint' of null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

The issue I'm facing is: every time I try to display a message from session I get an "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fingerprint' of null" error and after that I can't make any new ajax requests

The method called when I submit the form

```php
public function saveRolesPermissions()
    {
        $this->selectedPermissions = array_map(
            fn($permission) => array_filter($permission, fn($item) => $item != false),$this->selectedPermissions
        );

        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            if (array_key_exists($role->id, $this->selectedPermissions)) {
                $role->permissions()->sync($this->selectedPermissions[$role->id]);
            }
        };

        session()->flash('message', __('dashboard.Permissions updated'));
    }
```

The layout part where I read the session

```blade
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-3" role="alert">
        {{session('message')}}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
@endif
```

The error I get:

[image: Screenshot from console showing the mentioned error]

How do I solve this (apparently) session issue?

Comment: Can you share at which place you are calling the livewire component.

Comment: The component is called by web route

Comment: Please share that code.